# Плагин для гранта который собирает HTML

Tags: javascript, html, frontend, grunt, бэм

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой нибудь плагин для grunt, который бы собирал из html файлов одну страницу ну т.е. типа БЭМ? В идеале хотелось бы, что бы можно было просто прописать в странице index.html пути к файлам, а плагин, при запуске, заменил бы эти пути на содержимое этих файлов, создав тем самым, собранную HTML страницу.
*Самостоятельно нашёл  grunt-html-build  - но он какой то сильно мудрёный, хотелось бы что нибудь попроще, что бы просто прописывать пути к файлам прямо в файле Index.html, и не трогать gruntfile.js (хотя может grunt-html-build, это как раз то, что нужно, но я не верно его использую?)*

Comment: Хотите дать команду "фас" для гранта, но не хотите изменять файл с командами? Однако... Для сборки HTML у меня крутится **grunt-htmlmin**: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-htmlmin

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, можете попробовать [grunt-bake](https://github.com/MathiasPaumgarten/grunt-bake) или [grunt-include-replace](https://github.com/alanshaw/grunt-include-replace). Конфигурация для ваших целей будет минимальная.

Пример для grunt-bake:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <!--(bake includes/container.html)-->
        <!--(bake includes/footer.html)-->
    </body>
</html>
```

Пример для grunt-include-replace:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        @@include('includes/container.html')
        @@include('includes/footer.html')
    </body>
</html>
```