# Шаблонизация в обычном html

Tags: html, шаблонизаторы

Делаю интернет магазин, заказчик часто вносит правки - то футер переверстать, то хеадер, то карточку переделать. Такие компоненты встречаются на каждой странице и переписывать их вручную очень тяжко.

Хотелось бы иметь шаблонизатора который будет работать по принципу `include` в SCSS: совмещать отдельные файлы с обычным кодом и экспортировать в обычный `.html`.

Существуют такие решения?

Comment: Ну так собственно шаблонизаторов навалом и существует

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/519180/178988

Comment: А на чем ты таком делаешь интернет-магазин, где у тебя один из самых основных принципов программирования (DRY) не соблюдается?

Comment: DRY соблюдается, просто на каждой странице согласно дизайну должен быть хедер, футер, карточки товаров и тд. Внесешь правку в одно место и приходится править везде вручную.

Comment: Стоп-стоп-стоп...у тебя есть части, которые остаются неизменными во всем проекте, ты их правишь во всех файлах в проекте вместо использования даже самого банального инклюда файла, а сейчас говоришь, что dry соблюдается?

Comment: У вас особенное понимание dry как я вижу. В верстке постоянно повторяются элементы, например два оставленные вами комментария это два элемента с одинаковой разметкой.

Comment: @brachkoff, но разметка то одинаковая, и если шаблон поменяется, то все поменяется во всех местах сразу.

Comment: [SSI для Nginx](https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_ssi_module.html)

Comment: @Grundy именно это мне и нужно

Comment: @brachkoff, это к какому из комментариев ответ?